# JButton addActionListener(this);

Tags: java, awt, jbutton, this, actionlistener

I am curious as to why adding an actionListener to a JButton takes (this) as an argument when in the Java docs it says that addActionListener takes (ActionListener l) as an argument. They are different parameters and I was getting confused.

Here is the link to the Java doc I was using: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)

For example I can't do:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class AddButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

public AddButton(String name) {
    super(name);
    this.addActionListener(ActionListener l);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
    System.out.println("Worked so far!");
}

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your class implements ActionListener, and so `this` ***is*** an ActionListener. But remember, using `this` is ok for toy programs, but usually not for real production programs where you'll use other techniques.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thank you very much, that makes sense. Should I not still be able to use (ActionListener l) as an argument thought? And if I was not to use this, thankfully this is just a quick program, but what should I do instead?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @JoshM: It's a bad idea to create a GUI class (also known as a "view" class) that also implements the listener or "control" functions as you're asking the class to do too much which breaks the single responsibility rule of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I normally use :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MainClass extends JFrame{
private JButton chooseFile;
public MainClass(){// Constructor
super("Your Title");
chooseFile = new JButton("Choose File");
HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
chooseFile.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Button has been clicked");
}
}
}
```

Hope this helps you. This works for me all the time.